# Cannot delete element from django arrayfield

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to delete an element from an arrayfield in notes model

```
obj=notes.objects.get(id=n_id,related_to__contains=[c_id])
obj.related_to.remove(c_id)
obj.save()
```

where related to is the arrayfield

```
related_to=ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
```

n_id is the note's id and c_id is contact's id. When i try to do this i am getting the error **ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list** . I've checked and the c_id is in the arrayfield. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it finds the object, `c_id` is definitely in `related_to` field. I believe you are getting this error because `c_id` is not an `int` type but `string` type. You should first convert it to int:

```
c_id = int(c_id)
obj=notes.objects.get(id=n_id,related_to__contains=[c_id])
....
```

Comment: Oops. My bad. Didn't think about that. Works perfectly now. Thanks for pointing it out.